# Google tag manager adding &amp; instrad of just & into script src

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google tag manager to add the analytics script to my site, it is working correctly on most pages however seems to be inserting the scrip tag incorrectly on others.

It is using `&amp;` instead of just `&` in the analytics script tag src.

Example:

The tag created looks like this:

```
<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PZK7CW&amp;l=GoogleDataLayer">
```

not

```
<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PZK7CW&l=GoogleDataLayer">
```

See an example at: https://www.jumbolotto.de/marketing/gratis. It is loading correctly on the home page with the same google tag script.

The Google tag script looks like this

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PZK7CW" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','GoogleDataLayer','GTM-PZK7CW');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your Google tag manager script, you'll see that the ampersand is encoded.

```
dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';
```

You should check to make sure that the correct code is inserted into your page. Something in the process of copying the code from GTM to rendering the code on the page has encoded the ampersand.

Also, you should insert the GTM code immediately after the `<body>` tag and not at the bottom of the page just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: The google tag manager (GTM) script you are talking about is added by google tag manager, it is not something I am adding. GTM is doing the encoded of the ampersand.

Comment: No it is not. The code between <!-- Google Tag Manager --> and <!-- End Google Tag Manager --> is code you copied from GTM and inserted into your page. It is not put there by GTM.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry I miss misunderstand the bit of code you were talking about. The problem is now fixed.

Comment: And just to clarify, GTM *will* encode the ampersands in the debug panel. So if you open the "Custom HTML Tag - Fired 1 time(s)" and look at the injected HTML, it will show as encoded. But once it's actually injected into the DOM, it should not be encoded anymore.